# Recuperación de Datos con SQL y Laravel

Tags: sql

Muy buenas a todos. Vuelvo a consultaros mi problema:

Estoy realizando una página con laravel y MySQL que registra pedidos. Mi problema es que cuando se realizan varios registros al mismo tiempo desde diferentes dispositivos, mi base de datos solo me recupera el último registro insertado para todos los usuarios.

El sistema funciona bien a la hora de almacenar y devolver los registros, pero necesito que cada usuario vea únicamente los datos referentes al pedido que acaba de realizar.

El modelo es MVC. He añadido el siguiente filtro a la sentencia:

$sql="SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM pedidos) LIMIT 1";

Ésta sentencia me devuelve los datos del último pedido registrado y no conozco como asociar el dispositivo que está realizando el pedido con la inserción que se acaba de realizar. Básicamente necesito que me devuelva a cada usuario los datos del pedido que acaban de realizar.

Tras varios días buscando una solución no he dado con la fórmula correcta.

Agradezco cualquier comentario que me aporte alguna solución porque llevo días revisando documentación, tutoriales y foros pero no encuentro una solución.

PD: Mi formación al respecto es básica.

Un saludo.

Comment: Ruben cada insercion te retorna el valor del nuevo id, no necesitas consultarlo,segun esto estas usando laravel

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas consultar el id cada que insertas un datos ya que laravel te retorna el nuevo valor

```
$model = new MyModel($request->all());
 $model->save();
```

//donde $model ya se asigna el id automaticamente

si no estas usando laravel sino php nativo tambien lo puedes hacer

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
  echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: supongo que lo reemplazaste por el nombre de tu modelo ? Undefined type 'MyModel'

Comment: Porfavor provee algo de código

Comment: Tenías razón Cristian, lo solucioné con 'new MyModel'. 

Muchas graciás por su ayuda, saludos!